# I want to post computer vision api results into web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want once the page loads to do to the following code, however, I keep on getting an error saying "the modifier 'public' is not valid for this item" for public async Task MakeOCRRequest(). How can I fix this problem? I'm using computer vision API to capture text from an image.

```
  public void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        // Replace <Subscription Key> with your valid subscription key.
        const string subscriptionKey = "(*****)";

        // You must use the same region in your REST call as you used to
        // get your subscription keys. The paid subscription keys you will get
        // it from microsoft azure portal.
        // Free trial subscription keys are generated in the westcentralus region.
        // If you use a free trial subscription key, you shouldn't need to change
        // this region.
        const string endPoint =
            "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr";

        /// 
        /// Gets the text visible in the specified image file by using
        /// the Computer Vision REST API.
        /// </summary>

       public async Task<string> MakeOCRRequest()
        {
            string imageFilePath = @"C:\Users\rajeesh.raveendran\Desktop\bill.jpg";
            var errors = new List<string>();
            string extractedResult = "";
            ImageInfoViewModel responeData = new ImageInfoViewModel();
```

Comment: The posted code makes no sense as is. It shows a method, `page_Load` which defines two constants. It then attempts to define another method, inside the current method, which is not how C# works. You can define a *function* within a method, but not a method. Also, it's not clear what technology you're using. Maybe Web Forms?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I'm using Web froms. I'm new to programming, I want the method to fire once the page loads. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest that code. I would for testing simply drop a standard button into the form. double click on the button, and write the code behind in that resulting code stub.

Get that working first. You really don't want that code running on page load, since any refresh, or say dropping in several test buttons on that page will ALL cause the page load event to fire.

So, for now - being new at this? remove all that code from page load. Drop a button on the web form. Double click on the button, and then have your code inside of that button.

Also, don't use/create the code stub and call as async - since that will mean the whole page and it code values will go out of scope quite fast.

One can introduce the sub/task call eventually as async - but for starting out. Have teh page load - dispay that simple button. Click on the button and have the code stub (called code behind) run. And as noted, for starters don't call the addtional subs as asyc, since the web page works like this:

```
You click on a button.
The WHOLE web page travels up to server.
the page class object is created.
the page is pre-procssed.
your code behind NOW runs
when you code behind is done then page render is done
after page created, it travels back down to the client side
your page class then goes out of scope.
```

So, the last event - page class going out of scope is why you don't want to call that external sub as async, since if you do, then the web page travels back down to the client, and then page code class goes out of scope, but your "async" code is now running. (and you have no means to update the web form page.

So, break this testing + learning down into steps. Drop a button on the form desinger. Then double click on that button, and then in the IDE enter you code and sub calls.

Comment: So you're saying to put the above code into a  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) method?

Comment: yes. Use the form designer. Drag + drop in a button. Double click on that button (you are jumped to the code edtior when you do this). Now have/place/put/run the code in that button stub. and for testing - remove the async stuff - baby steps here.

Comment: In fact, why not drog in a text box onto that form - size it for a big paragraph. In property sheet for that text box change it to multi-line. Then on the last line of your code stub, put in a TextBox1.Text = "my results of code" (so you can display the results in a text box)